# ELASTİC SEARCH Querying by value within the same document

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "_source": {
    "listings": [
      {
        "product_list_id": "263",
        "product_price_ids": [361479]
      }
    ],
    "merchants": [
      {
        "merchantName": "gokhan",
        "price": 1111,
        "productPriceId": 360767
      },
      {
        "merchantName": "gunes",
        "productPriceId": 361479,
        "price": 5111
      }
    ],
    "name": "GÖKHAN GUNES PATH YAZILIM"
  }
}
```

I want to add a value from a nested field to the inner_hits query in Elasticsearch. I have the product_list_id = 263, and I want to find only the merchants associated with this product_list_id. Since the product_price_ids for the product_list_id 263 is ['361479'], the response should include:

```
{ 
"merchantName": "gunes",
"productPriceId": 361479, 
"price": 5111 
}
```

This value (361479) is unknown, and I need to retrieve merchants based on the values in the product_price_ids field for the list with product_list_id = 263.

Comment: Selam Gokhan, it looks the easiest way will be send multiple queries. First query for finding the `product_price_ids` field value which is **361479** in your case. The second query, a nested query, to find the correct match inside a nested field.

If you can explain the idea behind this logic, eg, why you don't know the `product_price_ids` in advance? I can help you more. 

An idea: if `product_price_ids` is updating frequently, during the update you can add `is_merchant: true/false` inside of each sub-fields. In that way, you can filter the results in nested.